# Sencha Cmd installation on Mac: Java not found

Tags: java, macos, extjs, installation

Trying to install Sencha Command 3.1.1 on my iMac (10.8.3).  The installer is saying:

```
The installer could not find a valid Java(tm) on this machine.
Supported versions: Vendor : Any  min. 1.6.0 max. any
```

Following another Stack Overflow thread, I tried linking /usr/bin/java to /Library/Internet Plugins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java.  Now, I get this on the command line:

```
~   java -version
java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)
```

So that looks good, but the installer still complains that it cannot find Java.  Why can't it?

Comment: On your terminal, just run "java" and see what it shows.. follow the on-screen instructions..

Comment: That's what I showed above, the results of running java -version from the command line.  From there, it's working fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What eventually fixed this for me, after consulting with Sencha support, was installing the full JDK rather than just the JRE.  I don't know exactly why this fixed it, or what the root cause was, but now Command installed successfully and is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had JDK installed, but one thing worked for me was exporting $java_home/bin:

```
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```